# special character in LIKE Operator with COALESCE is not working

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures, sql-like, coalesce

I have a Article table as shown below :

```
create table article(
  artID int,
  arttitle varchar(50)
  )
```

I have inserted 4 records in as below:

```
insert into article values (1,'abcd');
insert into article values (2,'asfsdf asdf sdf ');
insert into article values (3,'asdfasdfa sd ');
insert into article values (4,'abcasdfsdd [Little]');
```

created a test stored procedure:

```
create procedure test
@aID int = null,
@atit varchar(50) = null
as
select * from article where artID = COALESCE(@aID,artID) and 
arttitle like '%'+COALESCE(@atit,arttitle)+'%';
```

**Here is the problem :**
When I execute this `sp` with `aid = 1` it results with that record and similarly for `aid` 2 and 3.
But when I execute with `aid = 4` no results are coming becuase of those `square brackets [Little]`.

here is the stored procedure execution script :

```
exec test @aID = 4;
```

Please help me to achieve this. Thanks!
**Here is the sqlfiddle [link](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/8c9aa/14)**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't want to use any of the function you can directly check `is null`
Check bellow SQL.
`select * from article 
where (@aID is null or artID = @aID) and 
(@atit is null or arttitle  like '%'+ (@atit) +'%')`

Comment: This worked for me so marking it as answer. But I want to know the reason why special characters not been handled by COALESCE.

Comment: It's not `coalesce`, it's `like` operator.

Comment: @Evaldas : Yes if we want to use `COALESCE` in like query we need to use `ESCAPE '\'`. 
But, as of question I think just to check `is null` is enough to solve bug.

Answer (score 3):

This is because both `[]` are special characters and mean that one of the symbols, which is in brackets, must match. In order to fix it - you can escape these.

This is what you could do:

```
DECLARE @article TABLE
(
    artID INT
    , arttitle VARCHAR(50)
);

INSERT INTO @article
VALUES (1, 'abcd')
    , (2, 'asfsdf asdf sdf ')
    , (3, 'asdfasdfa sd ')
    , (4, 'abcasdfsdd [Little]');

DECLARE @aID INT = 4
    , @atit VARCHAR(50) = NULL

SELECT *
FROM @article
WHERE artID = COALESCE(@aID, artID)
    AND arttitle LIKE '%' + COALESCE(@atit, REPLACE(REPLACE(arttitle, '[', '\['), ']', '\]')) + '%' ESCAPE '\';
```

I've replaced `[` with `\[` and `]` with `\]` and escaped `\`, so that square brackets are treated as casual characters.

Comment: this was a part of very big stored procedure and table, user can enter anything square brackets , curly brackets, any special character. so including your changes will satisfy all conditions? or I have to do something else?

Comment: You should've mentioned this in your question. In that case this solutions is quite clumsy. I'd say go with solution, provided by Gordon Linoff. You won't have to escape special chars then.

Answer (score 2):

If you have special characters in the titles that you don't want processed by `like`, you could just use `charindex()`:

```
where @atit is null or charindex(@atit, artitle) > 0
```

If you want to use the wildcards, then `like` is a better choice.  But that doesn't seem to be your intention.

Actually, just using the explicit `@atit is null or` will fix your problem even with `NULL`.

Comment: so this will work even we execute procedure with @atit? I mean exec test @atit= 'abcd' will work?

Answer (score 0):

```
create table article(
artID int,
arttitle varchar(50)
)

insert into article values (1,'abcd');
insert into article values (2,'asfsdf asdf sdf ');
insert into article values (3,'asdfasdfa sd ');
insert into article values (4,'abcasdfsdd [Little]');

create procedure test
declare
as
@aID int =4,
@atit varchar(50) = null

select * from article where artID = COALESCE(@aID,artID) and (@atit is null or charindex(@atit, arttitle) > 0)
```